# Ionic push view over modal (need to login)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I have a mobile app where the user needs to re-login after some time for security reasons. The thing is that the content that was open in the background needs to stay there, and open after the login. So, even if it was a modal.
What is the best way to do this. 
Pushing the login view when a modal is open doesn't help, since the view is put behind the modal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open Login View as Modal, get data on `dismiss`, dismiss modal, your current page remains as it was, just update data received after dismissing modal.

Comment: check my answer for a little details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the current page

```
public openLogin() {
let loginModal = this.modalController.create(LoginPage, { modal: true });
loginModal.present();
loginModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
  if (data) {
    this.profileData = data;
  } else {
  }
});


 };
```

on loginPage

```
this.userService.login(username, password)
  .subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.success) {
      var user = data.result;
      this.userService.setSession(user);
      if (this.itsModal) {
       this.closeModal(data)
      }
      else {
        this.gotoHome();
      }
    } else {
      // error handling
    }

  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);      

  }

  );

public closeModal(data: any = null) {
this.viewController.dismiss(data);


 }
```